# Cannot display this video mode - Ubuntu 14.04 (32bit)

Tags: 14.04, boot

Quite similar to [Cannot Display This Video Mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438802/cannot-display-this-video-mode) which seems to have never been answered.

- Display works fine in liveCD but not in full installation.
- Full install boot I get the bios splash and then the screen goes black and screen resolution error message.
- If I try holding shift for grub, I get the bios splash, "loading grub", then screen resolution error message.
- Ctrl+Alt+F1 does nothing.
- Attempted to modify /etc/default/grub, changes are overwritten to defaults.
- sudo lshw -C display reveals I have a Rage 128 Pro agp card.
- System reboots if I press Ctrl+alt+del.

Suggestions?